# image appearing on top of eachother

Tags: html, css

i'm using target (same class and ID) so whenever user clicks on a word 3 images appear beside eachother however they are appearing on top of eachother, i've tried display:inline and also display:inline-block and float:left none of them worked (and no i can't use javascript to do it ): )
here's a sample of my code, if the whole document is needed let me know

```
     <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Acceuil</li>
            <li>Inscription</li>
            <a class="states" href="#link1"><li>States</li></a>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
        
        <a target="bas" href="C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Froud\Hangman\index.html"><img id="link1"  src="travel.png"></a>
        <a target="bas" href="C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Froud\Hangman\index.html"><img id="link1"  src="hh.png" ></a>
    </div>    
   
    <iframe name="bas"   width="100%" height="fit-content" style="margin-top: 200px;" ></iframe>

    li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    transition: font-size 2s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-name: anim;
}
li:hover{
   font-size: 50px;
   
}
ul{
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
}
#link1{
    display: none;
}
#link1:target{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
};

@keyframes anim{
    from{background-color: white;}
    to{background-color: teal;}
}
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}
.img2{
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique in HTML. No two should be the same.

Comment: well then how am i supposed to do this, my only solution for making an image appear is using :target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the same ID for two images, you should pass it to one `div` element. And then you can wrap your images in it.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  transition: font-size 2s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: anim;
}

li:hover {
  font-size: 50px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}

#link1 {
  display: none;
}

#link1:target {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

;
@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-color: white;
  }
  to {
    background-color: teal;
  }
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.img2 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Acceuil</li>
    <li>Inscription</li>
    <a class="states" href="#link1">
      <li>States</li>
    </a>
  </ul>

</div>
<div id="link1">
  <a target="bas" href="C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Froud\Hangman\index.html"><img style="width:100px" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/6f/ec/4b6fec352ad65acf6c1265201432dfa1.jpg"></a>
  <a target="bas" href="C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Froud\Hangman\index.html"><img style="width:100px" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/33/32/6d/33326dcddbf15c56d631e374b62338dc.jpg"></a>
</div>

<iframe name="bas" width="100%" height="fit-content" style="margin-top: 200px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: it worked but inline-block didn't work for some reason

Comment: Because html doesn't know hot to handle two elements with the same ID, so probably it was targeting just the first one it encounters.

Comment: Because now I'm targeting the entire div with the images as content, and not just the individual img